# How to create filtered category post loops in jekyll that don't repeat the same post

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to create a set of liquid loops to output jekyll posts by category. As some of my posts are in multiple categories I want to ensure that the same post isn't appearing as part of multiple loops.

Currently, my code for each loop looks something like this:

```
    {% for post in site.categories.photography limit:3 %}
        {% include post-item.html %}
    {% endfor %} 

    {% for post in site.categories.entrepreneurship limit:3 %}
        {% include post-item.html %}
    {% endfor %}
```

This works to output the posts in each category, but if a post is part of multiple categories it will appear multiple times. My thought is that perhaps as part of the loop I could mark each one as being 'used' and then exclude those from the next loop, but I can't get that functionality to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can store already printed posts title in an array.

```
{% assign already_printed = "" | split: "" %}

<ul>{% for p in site.categories.photography %}
  <li>{{ p.title }} - {{ p.categories | join: ", " }}</li>
  {%- assign already_printed = already_printed  | push: p.title %}
{% endfor %}</ul>

<ul>{% for p in site.categories.entrepreneurship %}
  {% unless already_printed contains p.title %}
    <li>{{ p.title }} - {{ p.categories | join: ", " }}</li>
  {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}</ul>
```